# SQL Flag By Group

Tags: sql, mysql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (STUDENT int, SCORE int, DATE date)
;
    
INSERT INTO t
    (STUDENT, SCORE, DATE)
VALUES
    (1, 6, '2022-02-01 00:00:00'),
    (1, 2, '2022-03-12 00:00:00'),
    (1, 5, '2022-04-30 00:00:00'),
    (2, 2, '2022-04-12 00:00:00'),
    (2, 0, '2022-04-17 00:00:00'),
    (2, 7, '2022-05-08 00:00:00'),
    (3, 2, '2022-03-16 00:00:00'),
    (3, 6, '2022-03-18 00:00:00'),
    (3, 2, '2022-04-02 00:00:00'),
    (3, 9, '2022-04-27 00:00:00'),
    (4, 4, '2022-02-24 00:00:00'),
    (4, 0, '2022-02-26 00:00:00'),
    (5, 3, '2022-01-28 00:00:00'),
    (5, 0, '2022-02-21 00:00:00'),
    (5, 4, '2022-04-05 00:00:00')
;
```

I wish to make a file like this:

[image: SELECT STUDENT, min(DATE) as min_date from t where SCORE = 2 group by STUDENT]

The rules is:

1. Find min(DATE) when SCORE = 2 and compare to min(DATE) when SCORE = 6
   A. If min(DATE, SCORE = 2) < min(DATE, SCORE = 6) then FLAG equals to 1
   B. If min(DATE, SCORE = 2) >= min(DATE, SCORE = 6) then FLAG equals to 0
   A. If STUDENT has record for SCORE = 2 but no record for SCORE = 6, then FLAG equals to 1

Comment: With that other request answered, you should be able to solve this yourself. I think, the other answer contains everything you need to solve this additional task. Come only here when you get stuck, not every time there is code to write.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner I tried this with no success 

SELECT student, MIN(CASE WHEN score = 2 THEN date END) AS min_date2, MIN(CASE WHEN score = 6 THEN date END) AS min_date6, 
case when min_date2 < min_date6 then 1 else 0;
from t
GROUP BY student
ORDER BY student
where min_date2>min_date6

Comment: It should look something like this: `select student, case when ... then 0 when ... then 1 ... end as flag from ...`.`

Comment: case when min_date2 < min_date6 then 1,
case when min_date2 >= min_date6 then 0 end as flag but how do i be sure to include flag=1 for STUDENTs who have a value =2 and no record of value=6 ?

Comment: What if they have no record for score=2?

Comment: @Barmar this is only for students with any score = 2, if they don't have that they are not in new table!

Answer (score 2):

You can use here - `MySQL CASE statement`

Below is the query to get the desired result.

```
WITH Score2And6 AS (
SELECT t.STUDENT,
       MIN(CASE WHEN t.SCORE = 2 THEN t.DATE ELSE NULL END) AS min_date_score_2,
       MIN(CASE WHEN t.SCORE = 6 THEN t.DATE ELSE NULL END) AS min_date_score_6
FROM t
WHERE t.SCORE IN (2, 6)
GROUP BY t.STUDENT)


SELECT score.STUDENT,
   CASE WHEN score.min_date_score_2 < score.min_date_score_6 OR score.min_date_score_6 IS NULL THEN 1
        ELSE 0
   END AS FLAG 
FROM Score2And6 score 
ORDER BY STUDENT ASC;
```

Here, I have used a CTE (Common Table Expression) to make the query more readable.

Demo: https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3zpma8neh

Answer (score 1):

Here you use the same approach with LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT t1.STUDENT,
CASE WHEN t2.min_date < t6.min_date OR t6.min_date IS NULL THEN 1
ELSE 0 END
FROM (SELECT STUDENT, min(DATE) as min_date
from t
where SCORE = 2
group by STUDENT) t2 LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT STUDENT, min(DATE) as min_date
from t
where SCORE = 6
group by STUDENT) t6 ON t2.STUDENT = t6.STUDENT
```

Comment: it generates error: ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 29: Unknown column 't2.min_date' in 'field list'

Comment: the alias for the first table  was wrong, i corrected it

Comment: Working fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/drfvzLMQRamcWWZ5vsFzN4/0

Comment: I already corrected it, thx @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

Be methodical when writing a query. Do it step by step. From your previous request you have all the information needed to create the query.

- You get the MIN(date) for a score n by `MIN(CASE WHEN score = n THEN date END)`
- You can limit the results to students with score m with `HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN score = m THEN 1 END) > 0`

Getting the dates for score 2 and 6 for all students that have a score 2 is hence:

```
SELECT 
  student,
  MIN(CASE WHEN score = 2 THEN date END) AS min_date_2,
  MIN(CASE WHEN score = 6 THEN date END) AS min_date_6
FROM t
GROUP BY student
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN score = 2 THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

Now you want to get flags depending on the minimum dates. You know you can use a `CASE` expression for this. There are two flag values: 0 if the score-2 date is greater or equal to the score-6 date, and 1 otherwise.

You can apply this right away in the above query

```
SELECT 
  student,
  CASE WHEN MIN(CASE WHEN score = 2 THEN date END) >=
            MIN(CASE WHEN score = 6 THEN date END)
    THEN 0
    ELSE 1
  END AS flag
...
```

or use a CTE (`WITH` clause) instead:

```
WITH cte AS ( <above query> )
SELECT
  student,
  CASE WHEN min_date_2 >= min_date_6 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS flag
FROM cte
ORDER BY student;
```